# PyZMQ Publisher socket stuck on send_string

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm making a ZMQ application which have a couple of thousands of subscribers, each sub runs in a different machine, ZMQ send is getting stuck and not sending anything, the only way that it works is when the Publisher binds on a port where only a few subs are connected (1 or 2 subs).

I've tried to use zmq.NOBLOCK and it is still getting stuck. It is not only getting stuck while sending, it is also getting stuck on any ZMQ socket related call for example when trying to get the events socket option (**socket.getsockopt(zmq.EVENTS)**).

Not even this minimal example is working (using python's interactive console)

```
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:{port}")

socket.send_string("whatever", zmq.NOBLOCK) # getting stuck here and not coming back
```

I have also tried using C and it kind of works, it gets stuck on the first send (up to 10 min) and the following sends work just fine.

C minimal example.

```
void *ctx = zmq_ctx_new();
void *socket = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_PUB);
zmq_bind(socket, "tcp://*:{port}");

int count = 1;
while (1) {
    if(count % 60 == 0){
        printf("Sending Message\n");
        zmq_send(socket, "whatever", 8, ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
        printf("Message Sent.\n");
    }
    count++;
    sleep (1);
}
```

**EDIT**

I get this when using strace on the python process.

```
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
...
...
...
write(9, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
write(9, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f7bfc000020, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
```

Is this maybe a deadlock in library's side?

**END EDIT**

Why is it getting stuck?
Could someone please help me out on this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Python==3.8.5 and pyzmq==19.0.2.
When I run your code (without any subscriber), mine doesn't get stuck, even when I'm not setting NOBLOCK flag.

If I do:

```
for i in range(100):
   print(i)
   socket.send_string("whatever")
```

It prints out 0 to 99 right away.

Comment: Yes, it works fine when there are just a few subs, but when the publisher has thousands of subs it gets stuck